# Fetch API - Pagination

Tags: fetch-api

recently I tried to learn how to get all the data while fetching paginated API's.
I came across this link https://observablehq.com/@xari/paginated_fetch.

```
import {is_required} from "@xari/is_required"
function paginated_fetch(
  url = is_required("url"), // Improvised required argument in JS
  page = 1,
  previousResponse = []
) {
  return fetch(`${url}&page=${page}`) // Append the page number to the base URL
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(newResponse => {
      const response = [...previousResponse, ...newResponse]; // Combine the two arrays

      if (newResponse.length !== 0) {
        page++;

        return paginated_fetch(url, page, response);
      }

      return response;
    });
}
```

How ever when I try to assign this function to a variable and console log nothing happening

```
let beers = paginated_fetch("https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?");
console.log(beers);
```

When I run in vscode

```
$ node run.js
Promise { <pending> }
$
```

Can anyone explain how can I console log this response and any explanation please.

Comment: the answer is "Promise { <pending> }" because your "paginated_fetch" function returns a promise, so you have to use the then() as described here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then